# Project Error (Eclipse) when creating Google Cloud Endpoint in GAE

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I created a simple project with GAE and i put in my package 'model' the PMF.java (Persistence Manager Factory Class) and a class (Employee.java).
After right-clicking the Employee class on Google->Generate Cloud Endpoint Class, the plugin correctly generate my EmployeeEndpoint, but after created that it appears an error on:

```
war->WEB-INF->lib
```

for this jar:

```
appengine-api-labs.jar
appengine-endpoints.jar
appengine-endpoints-deps.jar
```

And opening the ErrorLog of Eclipse, it just says:

```
An exception stack trace is not available
```

So clicking on the project to: Google->Generate Cloud Endpoint Client Library an error appears:

```
Error in Generating Client Libraries
```

with this message:

```
An error occurred when attempting to generate the client libraries
```

So, now that i'm facing this error, what could i do to solve the problem? Thank you so much in advance

[EDIT Error Log]:

```
Message:
Unexpected Exception


Exception Stack Trace:

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.GenerateSwarmApiAction$1.run(GenerateSwarmApiAction.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.server.spi.tools.ClientLibGenerator$Language
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmApiCreator.createClientLibFromApiConfig(SwarmApiCreator.java:113)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmApiCreator.createSwarmApi(SwarmApiCreator.java:258)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmServiceCreator.create(SwarmServiceCreator.java:444)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.GenerateSwarmApiAction$1.run(GenerateSwarmApiAction.java:80)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: Could you check the Problems View in Eclipse and see what the detail error is ?

Comment: I'll edit my Question with the ErroLog ;-)

Comment: I don't know how i resolve it. just 1) clean Project 2) Close All Projects 3)Re Open project 4) re-close project 5)closing and re-opening Eclipse 6)Open the project 7) Clean project 8)re try to generate Cloud Endpoint, and now works -.-" i'll add this as a response even if is stupid (not as stupid as Eclipse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) clean Project 2) Close All Projects 3)Re Open project 4) re-close project 5)closing and re-opening Eclipse 6)Open the project 7) Clean project 8)re try to generate Cloud Endpoint, and now works -.-" This is stupid, but not as stupid as Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem using Eclipse 4.3 with GAE version 1.9.6.

When I reverted to GAE version 1.8.8 the problem was solved immediately.

To revert right click your project -> Properties -> Google -> App Engine and choose an older version. I read somewhere that the problem came in since version 1.9.4.

Answer (score 0):

Re-name the endpoint class file to the standard format, Eg: "Earth.java" then it would work fine.